# Can two smart switches from different manufacturers be connected to become a two-way switch?

Tags: smart-switch

There is a light in the house which I would like to be able to control it via a bluetooth remote (from manufacturer A e.g. give the remote to a friend when I am out of town to somewhere without network access) or via an APP (from manufacturer B e.g. when I have network access)

Wondering if it is possible? or would anyone might have experience to share?

I'm new to smart-things, any ideas or corrections are also appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Do you have any existing smart switches? If so, name the manufacturers/models. If not, why not look for a manufacturer/product line which supports both local remotes and App access? Also don't limit yourself to Bluetooth. Nothing inherently wrong with Bluetooth, but there are other wireless technologies in use. If, for some reason, it **must** be Bluetooth, please explain.

Answer (score 2):

No.

A plain 2-way switch is also called an SPDT switch.  You put two of them back to back, like this.

[image]

Your wishful thinking goes like this: "I know that smart 2-ways can play nice with plain 2-ways. Therefore, surely, a smart 2-way *still is an SPDT switch that could mirror-image in either position... right?*"   No. That is wrong.

A smart 2-way switch does things its own way. It requires the wiring be rejiggered so it is provided "always-live" (so it can power itself and listen for network commands).  If a plain 2-way switch remains in the circuit, it is being used as a 1-way in the new configuration.

You might find a smart switch that can sit at the right side position, and take power off both travelers, recognizing *a change in* travelers as the other switch being thrown.  But that only works at the right side position, which is indeed where smart switches must be installed.  You will never find a smart switch that sits at the left position, alternating which of 2 output wires is live.

Further, there is zero interoperability between smart switches of various vendors.

Your only option is to identify a single smart-switch product which satisfies all your needs. You will be forced to install it in one location due to the wiring arrangement. If that's not the location you prefer, you will need to get a companion "remote" switch designed to work with the master, that hopefully has all the controls you want.